# Django template rendering error in Admin with ManyToMany field

Tags: python, django

Django is outputting an error while rendering a template for one of my models in the admin interface.  Specifically, I am trying to add a new entry in a model, and I'm getting the following error and traceback :

```
Template error:
In template C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\includes\fieldset.html, error at line 19
   'int' object is not iterable
   9 :             {% for field in line %}
   10 :                 <div{% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' %} class="fieldBox{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% if not field.is_readonly and field.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% if field.field.is_hidden %} hidden{% endif %}"{% elif field.is_checkbox %} class="checkbox-row"{% endif %}>
   11 :                     {% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' and not field.is_readonly %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
   12 :                     {% if field.is_checkbox %}
   13 :                         {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}
   14 :                     {% else %}
   15 :                         {{ field.label_tag }}
   16 :                         {% if field.is_readonly %}
   17 :                             <div class="readonly">{{ field.contents }}</div>
   18 :                         {% else %}
   19 :                              {{ field.field }} 
   20 :                         {% endif %}
   21 :                     {% endif %}
   22 :                     {% if field.field.help_text %}
   23 :                         <div class="help">{{ field.field.help_text|safe }}</div>
   24 :                     {% endif %}
   25 :                 </div>
   26 :             {% endfor %}
   27 :         </div>
   28 :     {% endfor %}
   29 : </fieldset>
```

The traceback can be viewed [here](http://dpaste.com/1KYHFQN)

Here are my models (A blog-entry and author):

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    entry_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    entry_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    entry_abstract = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    entry_thumbnail = models.ImageField(default='default.png', 
                                        upload_to='static/blog/images',
                                        blank=True)
    raw_entry = models.FileField(upload_to=raw_directory_path)
    html_content = models.FileField(blank=True)
    entry_slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    entry_authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, 
                    default=default_author)

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    head_shot = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog/authors', blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
```

I originally thought the error was caused by modifying my admin interface with attributes like admin.ModelAdmin.list_display (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#ManyToManyField-fields-aren%E2%80%99t-supported) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models)), but I disabled add custom admin interfaces and the error still persists.

I'm going to keep reading the admin interface documents in django.  Is there anything special I need to do for allowing ManyToMany fields in the django admin?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  I was specifying a default in my ManyToMany field like so :

```
def default_author():
    """get or create the pk of the deafult author. This should
    be an author with name Anonymous"""
    try:
        author = Author.objects.get(first_name__exact='Anonymous', 
                                    last_name__exact='Author')
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        author = Author(first_name='Anonymous',
                        last_name='Author')
        author.save()

    return author.id

class Entry(models.Model):
    entry_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    entry_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    entry_abstract = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    entry_thumbnail = models.ImageField(default='default.png', 
                                        upload_to='static/jv_blog/images',
                                        blank=True)
    raw_entry = models.FileField(upload_to=raw_directory_path)
    html_content = models.FileField(blank=True)
    entry_slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    entry_authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, 
                    default=default_author)
```

The correct way to set a default value in a ManyToMany field is to re-implement the models save() method.  I will update this answer with my solution if I remember to do so..